# Disassembling c function in Ida pro

Tags: c, function

I am an intermediate "C" learner. I have written a simple function in c,compiled(Released) sucessfully.
I learned that adding extern "C" to function prohibits compiler from mangling it's name. so, i added extern "C" to my function but after dropping it to ida pro why i could not locate my function name ?

It contains few function but with some sub prefix other are compiler specific,i could not find the function i compiled.

If my way of disassembling function is wrong then please suggest it, I know it could be done in Visual editor while building but i want it other way.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're building an executable. Names get preserved for exported items only, when you are building a library. When you build an executable, the names (mangled or not) can be discarded (by the compiler and linker) because they are no longer needed - references to functions and variables within the executable are all done numerically.

If you build your code as a library (`.dll`/`.so`/`.dylib` depending on platform) and mark your functions as exported, you will see the names.

You can also see the names if you use IDA to look at the intermediate object files (`.o`/`.obj`). Those still contain names because the linker needs them to find functions by name during the linking process.

Finally, there is one way you can get function names to appear in IDA - build your executable with symbols enabled (i.e. produce a `.pdb` file if you're using MS tools). IDA will notice and offer to load the symbols, which will associate names with functions.

Comment: I am building executable but not .dll (Window's). is it possible to find the target function by disassemble only .exe.

Comment: There is a possibility. Edited the answer.

Comment: Adding  extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )  to function in declaration